# Numpy's eigh and eig yield inconsistent eigenvalues

Tags: python, numpy

Currently I'm trying to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem in NumPy for two symmetric matrices and I've been running into massive trouble as I'm expecting all eigenvalues to be positive, but `eigh` returns several very large numbers that are not all positive, while `eig` returns the correct, expected values (but is, of course, very, very slow).

In this case, note that `K` is symmetric as expected from its construction (here is the code in question):

```
# Calculate K matrix (<i|pHp|j> in the LGL-nodes basis)
for i in range(Ne):
    idx_s, idx_e = i*(Np-1), i*(Np-1)+Np
    K[idx_s:idx_e, idx_s:idx_e] += dmat.T.dot(diag(w*peq[idx_s:idx_e])).dot(dmat)

# Re-make matrix for efficient vector products
K = sparse.csr_matrix(K)

# Make matrix for <i|p|j> in the LGL basis as efficient diagonal sparse matrix
S = sparse.diags(peq*w_d, 0)

# Solve the generalized eigenvalue problem: Kc = lSc for hermitian matrices K and S
lQ, Q = linalg.eigh(K.todense(), S.todense())
_lQ, _Q = linalg.eig(K.todense(), S.todense())

lQ.sort()
_lQ.sort()

if not allclose(lQ, _lQ):
    print('Literally why')
    print(lQ)
    print(_lQ)
return
```

For testing, `dmat` is defined as

```
array([[ -896.        ,  1212.00631086,  -484.43454844,   275.06612251,
         -179.85209531,   124.26620323,   -83.05199285,    32.        ],
       [ -205.43460499,     0.        ,   290.78944413,  -135.17191772,
           82.83085126,   -55.64467829,    36.70818656,   -14.07728095],
       [   50.7185076 ,  -179.61445086,     0.        ,   184.03311398,
          -87.85829324,    54.08144362,   -34.37053351,    13.01021241],
       [  -23.81762789,    69.05246008,  -152.20398294,     0.        ,
          152.89115899,   -72.66291308,    42.31407046,   -15.57316561],
       [   15.57316561,   -42.31407046,    72.66291308,  -152.89115899,
            0.        ,   152.20398294,   -69.05246008,    23.81762789],
       [  -13.01021241,    34.37053351,   -54.08144362,    87.85829324,
         -184.03311398,     0.        ,   179.61445086,   -50.7185076 ],
       [   14.07728095,   -36.70818656,    55.64467829,   -82.83085126,
          135.17191772,  -290.78944413,     0.        ,   205.43460499],
       [  -32.        ,    83.05199285,  -124.26620323,   179.85209531,
         -275.06612251,   484.43454844, -1212.00631086,   896.        ]])
```

And all of `w[i]`, `w_d[i]`, `peq[i]` are essentially arbitrary positive-valued arrays. `w_d` and `w` are of the same order (~ 1e-1) and `peq[i]` ranges on the order of (~ 1e-10 to 1e1)

Some of the output I'm getting is

```
Literally why
[ -6.25540943e+07  -4.82660391e+07  -2.62629052e+07 ...,   1.07960873e+10
   1.07967334e+10   4.26007915e+10]
[ -5.25462340e-12+0.j   4.62614812e-01+0.j   1.23357898e+00+0.j ...,
   2.17613917e+06+0.j   1.07967334e+10+0.j   4.26007915e+10+0.j]
```

EDIT:

Here's a self-contained version of the code for easier debugging

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
from scipy import sparse, linalg

# Variable declarations and such (pre-computed)
Ne, Np = 256, 8
N = Ne*Np - Ne + 1
domain_size = 4/Ne


x = np.array([-0.015625  , -0.01362094, -0.00924532, -0.0032703 ,  0.0032703 ,
    0.00924532,  0.01362094,  0.015625  ])
w = np.array([ 0.00055804,  0.00329225,  0.00533004,  0.00644467,  0.00644467,
    0.00533004,  0.00329225,  0.00055804])
dmat = np.array([[ -896.        ,  1212.00631086,  -484.43454844,   275.06612251,
     -179.85209531,   124.26620323,   -83.05199285,    32.        ],
   [ -205.43460499,     0.        ,   290.78944413,  -135.17191772,
       82.83085126,   -55.64467829,    36.70818656,   -14.07728095],
   [   50.7185076 ,  -179.61445086,     0.        ,   184.03311398,
      -87.85829324,    54.08144362,   -34.37053351,    13.01021241],
   [  -23.81762789,    69.05246008,  -152.20398294,     0.        ,
      152.89115899,   -72.66291308,    42.31407046,   -15.57316561],
   [   15.57316561,   -42.31407046,    72.66291308,  -152.89115899,
        0.        ,   152.20398294,   -69.05246008,    23.81762789],
   [  -13.01021241,    34.37053351,   -54.08144362,    87.85829324,
     -184.03311398,     0.        ,   179.61445086,   -50.7185076 ],
   [   14.07728095,   -36.70818656,    55.64467829,   -82.83085126,
      135.17191772,  -290.78944413,     0.        ,   205.43460499],
   [  -32.        ,    83.05199285,  -124.26620323,   179.85209531,
     -275.06612251,   484.43454844, -1212.00631086,   896.        ]])

# More declarations
x_d = np.zeros(N)
w_d = np.zeros(N)
dmat_d = np.zeros((N, N))

for i in range(Ne):
    x_d[i*(Np-1):i*(Np-1)+Np] = x+i*domain_size
    w_d[i*(Np-1):i*(Np-1)+Np] += w
    dmat_d[i*(Np-1):i*(Np-1)+Np, i*(Np-1):i*(Np-1)+Np] += dmat

peq = (np.cos((x_d-2)*pi/4))**2

# Normalization
peq = peq/np.sum(w_d*peq)
p0 = np.maximum(peq, 1e-10)
p0 /= np.sum(p0*w_d)

# Make efficient matrix that can be built
K = sparse.lil_matrix((N, N))

# Calculate K matrix (<i|pHp|j> in the LGL-nodes basis)
for i in range(Ne):
    idx_s, idx_e = i*(Np-1), i*(Np-1)+Np
    K[idx_s:idx_e, idx_s:idx_e] += dmat.T.dot(np.diag(w*p0[idx_s:idx_e])).dot(dmat)

# Re-make matrix for efficient vector products
K = sparse.csr_matrix(K)

# Make matrix for <i|p|j> in the LGL basis as efficient diagonal sparse matrix
S = sparse.diags(p0*w_d, 0)

# Solve the generalized eigenvalue problem: Kc = lSc for hermitian matrices K and S
lQ, Q = linalg.eigh(K.todense(), S.todense())
_lQ, _Q = linalg.eig(K.todense(), S.todense())

lQ.sort()
_lQ.sort()

if not np.allclose(lQ, _lQ):
    print('Literally why')
    print(lQ)
    print(_lQ)
```

<del>EDIT2: This is really odd. Running all of the NumPy/SciPy tests on my machine, I receive no errors. But even running the simple test (with large enough matrices) as</del>

```
import numpy as np
from spicy import linalg

M = np.random.random((1000,1000))
M += M.T

np.allclose(sorted(linalg.eigh(M)[0]), sorted(linalg.eig(M)[0]))
```

<del>fails on my machine. Though running the same test with a 50x50 matrix does work---even after rebuilding the SciPy/NumPy stack and passing all unit tests.</del>

<del>EDIT3: Actually, this seems to fail everywhere, after testing it on a cluster computer. I'm not sure why.</del>

The above fails due to the in-place behaviour of `+=` and `.T` as a view rather than an operation.

Comment: what is domain_size?

Comment: @maxymoo Sorry, fixed that and the `dL` mistake. I'm running this on an IPython notebook which is why some stuff is not declared explicitly.

Comment: Also fix `zeros` -> `np.zeros`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Ah, crap. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: ... and many more...

Comment: Well, a few more, anyway: `cos`, `pi`, `diag`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Just noticed those when I ran it on vanilla python. Everything should(?) be fixed now... hopefully.

Comment: It runs with no output for me (i.e. the results are the same within the tolerance of `np.allclose()`).  I'm using scipy 0.15.1 and numpy 1.9.2 on a Mac.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser That's absolutely odd, [I'm running *exactly* the same setup](http://i.imgur.com/e9Ckl0d.png) and the test completely fails for me.